# C# / mono hanging on AppDomain.Unload

Tags: c#, mono, appdomain

Our app runs several different AppDomains in order to work around a limitation in a 3rd party API we're using.

Intermittently (say 1 in 8 times) when we attempt to unload the AppDomain, using `AppDomain.Unload(appDomain)`, the entire app hangs with no warning, and does not respond to SIGQUIT, making it difficult to debug the issue.

There is no unmanaged code in our codebase, though it's possible that one of the libraries (including Npgsql) we're using may contain some.

Googling the issue shows a number of references to hangs on AppDomain.Unload, but these have supposedly been fixed in the version of  Mono we're using (4.03).

Running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help / pointers greatly appreciated!

Simplified version of the code below:

```
AppDomain appDomain = null;
try {
    appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some unique name");
    batchProcessor = (MarshaledProcessor)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        MarshalledProcessorType.Assembly.FullName,
        MarshalledProcessorType.FullName);

        batchProcessor.ProcessItems();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    Log.Error("some error", exception);
} finally {
    try {
        if (batchProcessor != null) {
            batchProcessor.Dispose();
        }
        if (appDomain != null) {
            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.Error(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's supposed to eventually trip a CannotUnloadAppDomainException.  Two basic ways you can deal with this.  You can dig in and fix the bug that prevents that exception from being generated, the open source way.  But then you'll have a fairly nasty exception that's pretty difficult to deal with, you meant to unload the appdomain but it didn't happen, what do you do next?  Or you tame those threads that run in the appdomain so you can be sure that you don't try to unload until they are done.  Now you fixed both problems.  If they can't be tamed then run them in another process.

Comment: Thanks Hans! Do you have any suggestions on how best to determine which threads have not terminated? In our code, there should only be a single thread per AppDomain. Usually I'd debug an issue like this using SIGQUIT or gdb, but once the app hangs at this point, neither of these seems to bear fruit.